# Zend_db only gives a error in my main module and only when I use 'woningen' as table name

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

This is the code I use to update/insert data in my database.

```
public function saveItem($post, $table)
    {
        unset($post['submit']);
        $this->_table = new Zend_Db_Table($table); exit;

        if (isset($post['id'])) {
            $where = $this->_table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $post['id']);
            $this->_table->update($post, $where);
            return $post['id'];
        } else {
            return $this->_table->insert($post);
        }
    }
```

For some reason

```
$this->_table = new Zend_Db_Table($table);
```

Gives me a error but only when $table = 'woningen' and only in my main module.

### Here is the error:

```
APPLICATION ERROR
EXCEPTION INFORMATION:
Message: Argument must be of type Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract, or a Registry key where a Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract object is stored
STACK TRACE:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(581): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::_setupAdapter('woningen')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(283): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setAdapter('woningen')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(265): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->setOptions(Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Db\Table.php(77): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\application\models\Inlog.php(109): Zend_Db_Table->__construct('woningen')
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\application\modules\default\controllers\WoningmandjeController.php(157): Application_Model_Inlog->saveItem(Array, 'woningen')
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): WoningmandjeController->sendAction()
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('sendAction')
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\makeltrent.website\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

---

Comment: If it fails when it's 'woningen', what do you use when it succeeds?

Comment: Anything works, even 'HKJHawfdFDSFhjadnkjioopwqeipdjASLKdjKJSlj' doesn't give me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought, as explained by the error message, is that you have a Zend_Registry key by that name, but not an object of something like a `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`, which is what it's expecting. A random string would not fail for that reason, since it would end up returning `false`, or `null` - which simply returns out of the `_setupAdapter` function without doing anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! ILOVEYOU!! -nohomo-

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an problem with your class setup.

Zend_Db_Table **needs the DB Adapter** to initalize not the Tablename. You can altough define your Adapter as Default DB Adapter in your application.ini.

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "host"
resources.db.params.dbname = "database"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Comment: I already have that, my code works fine except when I'm in the default module and I use 'woningen' as table name.